# Why does the game crash every time I complete a level under development using the Puzzle Maker?

Tags: portal-2

The title explains it all. Every time I complete a level currently under development using the built-in puzzle maker, the game crashes when I reach the "Test complete. Restarting..." screen. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

I have had this problem before, and for me it helped to reinstall the game.  I have contacted steam support, and they haven't been able to provide me with a better solution.

A simple work-around would be to stop at the end of your chamber, and not actually exit it. Then switch to build mode with tab, and rebuild the room when you want to test again.

Some mods seem to cause this problem. Try removing them, and installing them one at a time to see which mod causes trouble